# 構造体のポインタが上手く使えません

Tags: c

二分探索木をc言語で実装するときに，わからない部分がありました．
実装したコードは以下のとおりです．

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int value;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
    } Node;

Node* makenode1(int value){
    Node newnode={value, NULL, NULL};
    Node* n = & newnode;
    printf("n->left①：%p\n", n->left);
    printf("n->right①：%p\n", n->right);
    return n;
}

Node* makenode2(double x){
    Node* n = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (n != NULL) {
        n->value = x;
        n->left = NULL;
        n->right = NULL;
    }
    printf("n->left①：%p\n", n->left);
    printf("n->right①：%p\n", n->right);
    return n;
}

Node* insert(Node* n, int value, int makenodetype){
    if(n==NULL){
        if(makenodetype==1) n = makenode1(value);
        else n = makenode2(value);
        printf("n->left②：%p\n", n->left);
        printf("n->right②：%p\n", n->right);
    }else{
        if(value < n->value){
            n->left = insert(n->left, value, makenodetype);
        }
        else{
            n->right = insert(n->right, value, makenodetype);
        }
    }
    return n;
}

int main(void){
    printf("----------1----------\n");
    Node* root1 = NULL;
    int makenodetype = 1;
    root1 = insert(root1, 5, makenodetype);
    printf("root1->value：%d\n", root1->value);
    printf("root1->left：%p\n", root1->left);
    printf("root1->right：%p\n", root1->right);
    printf("----------2----------\n");
    Node* root2 = NULL;
    makenodetype = 2;
    root2 = insert(root2, 5, makenodetype);
    printf("root2->value：%d\n", root2->value);
    printf("root2->left：%p\n", root2->left);
    printf("root2->right：%p\n", root2->right);
    printf("---------------------\n");
    return 0;
}
```

私の環境での実行結果は以下のとおりです．

```
----------1----------
n->left①：0x0
n->right①：0x0
n->left②：0x0
n->right②：0x7ffeeb34c790
root1->value：16
root1->left：0x7ffeeb34c870
root1->right：0x7ffeeb34c790
----------2----------
n->left①：0x0
n->right①：0x0
n->left②：0x0
n->right②：0x0
root2->value：5
root2->left：0x0
root2->right：0x0
---------------------
```

makenode1を用いた場合（makenodetype=1とした場合）では上手く動作しません．
なぜ，n->right①：0x0とn->right②：0x7ffeeb34c790で値が違うのでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

auto 変数はスタック領域に用意され, 関数を抜ける際に開放されます
それに対し, `malloc()` の場合はヒープ領域で, (`free()` で)明示的に開放(あるいはプログラム終了)するまで残ります

以下のコードで, `newnode`, `n` は `return` 時に消えてしまいます。
戻り値としての `n` の値は呼び出し元に返るけど, そのポインターが指し示す先は何が入ってるか不定
(単純に関数から戻るだけなら 破壊されない可能性もあるけど, 割り込みなどの要因もあるので)

```c
Node* makenode1(int value){
    Node newnode={value, NULL, NULL};
    Node* n = & newnode;
    printf("n->left①：%p\n", n->left);
    printf("n->right①：%p\n", n->right);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: 理解できました，丁寧な解説ありがとうございます！